# Remote server not allowing cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am sending request by cURL to server by following code, and it is giving permission error as "Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server".
the cURL code is...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "key=".$my_key);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, site_url()); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $res;
```

anybody please guide me what is error, or what should I do to resolve issue.
thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the headers that are you sending? Maybe the server is filtering something using the headers that you are sending.

Comment: This is all, I am not sending anything else, this code is in function and I am calling function.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Try to set an user-agent and see if it works.  

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0');`

Comment: This is error I am receiving

You don't have permission to access /my_admin/class_name/function_name on this server.
Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at domain_url Port 80

Request receiver is codeignitor

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be related to `SSL` i.e. `https` request. You can ignore verification by adding below lines:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: I have added that, and the header posted above, but no success. using print_r the result is giving this error.....You don't have permission to access /my_admin/class_name/function_name on this server.
Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at domain_url Port 80

Request receiver is codeignitor

Comment: Codeigniter prevents direct script access for security purpose. Are you able to access the URL which is being passed in CURL through browser?

Comment: Yes, when I hit that URL manually, it gives me results of json